# Schedule a job through a web app using user input

Tags: java, jsp, quartz-scheduler

I am using the quartz scheduler. And I can schedule jobs in the usual way without any problem.

**Code**

```
public class QuartzTest implements Job {

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {
                System.out.println("Hello Quartz on " + new Date());
            }

    public static Scheduler scheduler;

    public void scheduleLoad(String time, int jobNo) {
        try {
            // Transform user input into a date
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy:HH:mm:ss");
            Date scheduleDate = dateFormat.parse(time);

            // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory 
            //Scheduler 
            scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

            // Listener
            //scheduler.getListenerManager().addJobListener(new SimpleJobListener());

            // and start it if it is shut down
            if(!scheduler.isStarted())
                scheduler.start();

            // Define a job and tie it to a class
            JobDetail job = newJob(QuartzTest.class)
                    .withIdentity("job"+jobNo)
                    .build();

            // Define trigger 
            SimpleTrigger trigger = (SimpleTrigger) newTrigger()
                    .startAt(scheduleDate)
                    .forJob("job"+jobNo)
                    .build();

            // Schedule job using trigger
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException {
        String runTime = "04/15/2013:17:37:10";
        QuartzTest quartz = new QuartzTest();
        quartz.scheduleLoad(runTime,1);
        String runTime2 = "04/15/2013:17:37:15";
        quartz.scheduleLoad(runTime2,2);
        String runTime3 = "04/15/2013:17:37:20";
        quartz.scheduleLoad(runTime3,3);
    }
}
```

But I have to create a web app, in which I have to schedule a job using the "user's input". This is where I am getting stuck. How do I do this ? I will be using JSP.

e.g.- **User 1's command** - /home/user/load.sh -a -b -c (schedule on Monday)
**User 2's command** - /home/user/load.sh -a -b -g (schedule on Tuesday)

I can take the user's command, schedule date, etc from the web page as a string and then parse this string later inside Quartz scheduler. But how do I pass this string to Quartz in the first place to schedule the user's job ?

Just to make myself clear-
**I want the user to be able to define his own job and schedule.**

Thanks

Comment: `jsp != webapp`. Take a look at [`servlets`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: Dont the `jsp` scriptlets get compiled into a `servlet` ?

Comment: Sure, but don't do it that way. It's bad practice.

Comment: `jsp` is compiled to a `servlet`, but it belongs to the presentation layer of your web application (where you generate your output). The logic of your web application should be in your servlet/controller.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the i/p. But any solution to my original question ? Even a servlet approach would suffice.

Comment: @kaustavdatta The link I posted shows how to get user input through `request` parameters. You would have a `form` in your jsp. And when you submit that form, the `input` parameters would be available in the `jsp`. You take those and generate/schedule your `quartz` job.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Getting the input is not the problem, problem is how to keep on adding jobs dynamically to the Quartz scheduler. Since we cannot pass a String argument to the `execute(JobExecutionContext context)` method.

Comment: @kaustavdatta Isn't that what your `scheduleLoad(String, int)` method is for? Move it to another class that is only used for scheduling jobs.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `scheduleLoad(String, int)` lets me only load the hard coded job i.e. `System.out.println("Hello Quartz on " + new Date())`. It is this job which I want to be dynamic, users should be able to define their own job + the schedule.

Comment: @kaustavdatta One of the input parameters you can have is which type of job to schedule. You can have one that prints the time, another that deletes a file, another that updates a counter in a database, etc. When the request goes through, you will decide, based on the input, which job to schedule.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That is not feasible as there are hundreds of types of jobs in my requirement.

Comment: @kaustavdatta These jobs are your requirement, you can't expect users to input that kind of information, unless you have some powerful API that can understand it, but that is a completely different subject than the question you posted.

Comment: @kaustavdatta For example, what are the limits of the jobs they can define? Can they access the file system, databases, other processes running? You need an interface for defining jobs.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/28258

Comment: @kaustavdatta Look at my answer. If a user makes a POST request to, example, `www.domain.com/context/jobs` with whatever request parameters included in the body of the HTTP request, you can extract those and pass them to the `sh` script. In the html, any `<input>` elements will be passed as http request parameters to the servlet handling the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a class that extends `HttpServlet` that is registered in your application's `web.xml` file. Again, take a look at the [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), for how to do this

```
@WebServlet("/jobs") // only with Servlet 3.0  
public class SchedulerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // get input parameter
        String time = request.getParameter("time");
        // validate that it is not null/empty and is valid time (custom method)
        if (time != null && !time.isEmpty() && isValidTime(time)) {
            int jobNo = ... // generate job no
            YourJobScheduler scheduler = ... // get scheduler
            JobDetails jobDetails = scheduler.scheduleLoad(time, jobNo); // maybe this return details of the scheduled job

            request.setAttribute("jobDetails", jobDetails);             
            // do something with response
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/ShowJobDetails.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

        // missing input parameter, so send error 
    }
}
```

This class will take the input parameter `time`, validate it, and then pass it to your scheduler, which is basically the method you have in your question, except maybe it returns an object containing the details of the job you just scheduled. If you add that object to your request attributes, you can then show it in your View (as a `jsp`).